# tcl add counter to identical list values

Tags: list, tcl, counter

I have a list with values:

```
set unnumbered [list 101 101 101 102 102 103 104 105 105 105 106]
```

I want to add a counter to subsequent identical values like this:

```
numbered [ 101.1 101.2 101.3 102.1 102.2 103 104 105.1 105.2 105.3 106]
```

So far I have tried the following:

```
set unnumbered [list 101 101 101 102 102 103 104 105 105 105 106]
set numbered [list ]
set previous [lindex $unnumbered 0]
set subcounter 1

foreach current $unnumbered  {

        if { $current eq $previous } {
                lappend numbered $current.$counter
                set previous $current
                incr subcounter
        } else {        
                lappend numbered $current
                set previous $current
                set subcounter 1
                }
}
```

The result is almost what I need.

```
101.1 101.2 101.3 102 102.1 103 104 105 105.1 105.2 106
```

For all but the first value, the Counter starts to Count to late. The first 102 laks the ".1"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code doesn't have enough information at the point where a number is added to `numbered`. Get the information first, and then apply it.

First, create a list where each item is a list consisting of one of the unique numbers in `$unnumbered` and the indices in `$unnumbered` where that number occurs:

```
lmap n [lsort -unique $unnumbered] {
   list $n [lsearch -all $unnumbered $n]
}
# => {101 {0 1 2}} {102 {3 4}} {103 5} {104 6} {105 {7 8 9}} {106 10}
```

For each of those items, split up the item into `n` = the number and `indices` = the indices. Check how many indices you have. For more than one index, add enumerated numbers like this:

```
set i 0
foreach index $indices {
    lappend numbered $n.[incr i]
}
```

For single indices, just add the number:

```
lappend numbered $n
```

The whole program looks like this:

```
set unnumbered [list 101 101 101 102 102 103 104 105 105 105 106]
set numbered [list]

foreach item [lmap n [lsort -unique $unnumbered] {
    list $n [lsearch -all $unnumbered $n]
}] {
    lassign $item n indices
    if {[llength $indices] > 1} {
        set i 0
        foreach index $indices {
            lappend numbered $n.[incr i]
        }
    } else {
        lappend numbered $n
    }
}
```

Documentation:
[> (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm),
[lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

If you don’t have `lmap`, see the link above. If you don’t have `lassign`, use

```
foreach {n indices} $item break
```

instead.

**ETA** If the "no index on singleton numbers" requirement can be relaxed, one could do it this way:

```
set previous {}
lmap num $unnumbered {
    if {$num ne $previous} {
        set i 0
    }
    set previous $num
    format %d.%d $num [incr i]
}
```

Another variant. It’s very similar to Jerry’s second suggestion, but I didn’t see that one until I was going to submit this, honest. This one assumes that no element in `$unnumbered` is the empty string.

```
set numbered [list]
set rest [lassign $unnumbered current next]
set i 0
while 1 {
    if {$current eq $next} {
        lappend numbered $current.[incr i]
    } else {
        if {$i > 0} {
            lappend numbered $current.[incr i]
            set i 0
        } else {
            lappend numbered $current
        }
        set current $next
    }
    if {$next eq {}} break
    set rest [lassign $rest next]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: maintain a dict to keep the count of what you've seen so far

```
set unnumbered [list 101 101 101 102 102 103 104 105 105 105 106]
set count [dict create]
set numbered {}
foreach num $unnumbered {
    dict incr count $num
    lappend numbered "$num.[dict get $count $num]"
}
puts $numbered
```

```
101.1 101.2 101.3 102.1 102.2 103.1 104.1 105.1 105.2 105.3 106.1
```

Using an array is a little simpler: taking advantage of the fact that `incr` returns the new count

```
set numbered {}
array set count {}
foreach num $unnumbered {lappend numbered "$num.[incr count($num)]"}
```

---

OK, I missed the requirement that singleton entries should not have a suffix. There's this, but it *may* re-order the initial list:

```
set count [dict create]
foreach num $unnumbered {dict incr count $num}
set numbered {}
foreach num [dict keys $count] {
    set c [dict get $count $num]
    if {$c == 1} {
        lappend numbered $num
    } else {
        for {set i 1} {$i <= $c} {incr i} {
            lappend numbered "$num.$i"
        }
    }
}
puts $numbered
```

```
101.1 101.2 101.3 102.1 102.2 103 104 105.1 105.2 105.3 106
```

Or, this maintains the original order

```
set count [dict create]
foreach num $unnumbered {dict incr count $num}
foreach key [dict keys $count] {
    if {[dict get $count $key] == 1} {
        set count [dict remove $count $key]
    }
}

set numbered {}
foreach num [lreverse $unnumbered] {
    if {![dict exists $count $num]} {
        lappend numbered $num
    } else {
        lappend numbered "$num.[dict get $count $num]"
        dict incr count $num -1
    }
}
set numbered [lreverse $numbered]
puts $numbered
```

```
101.1 101.2 101.3 102.1 102.2 103 104 105.1 105.2 105.3 106
```

Comment: Good solution, but doesn't help if one wants to keep singleton numbers unindexed.

Comment: Right, missed that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

An O(n) solution (single loop), and which I believe looks a bit more like how you initially wanted to implement it:

```
set unnumbered [list 101 101 101 102 102 103 104 105 105 105 106]
set numbered [list]
set previous ""
set subcounter 1

foreach current $unnumbered  {
  if {$previous == ""} {
    # First, do nothing except set $current to $previous later below
  } elseif {$previous == $current} {
    lappend numbered $previous.$subcounter
    incr subcounter
  } else {
    if {$subcounter > 1} {
      lappend numbered $previous.$subcounter
    } else {
      lappend numbered $previous
    }
    set subcounter 1
  }
  set previous $current
}

if {$subcounter > 1} {
  lappend numbered $current.$subcounter
} else {
  lappend numbered $current
}
```

The loop basically adds one number late to the `numbered` list, so that the last `if` is required for the last number. Of course, this only works if you know that `unnumbered` is sorted.

---

EDIT: Actually this is even closer! Since you can already get `$previous`, you can loop starting from the next element of the list, and one last time after the last element (note that we get a blank if the `lindex` is supplied with an out of range index, which makes things easier here).

```
set unnumbered [list 101 101 101 102 102 103 104 105 105 105 106]
set numbered [list]
set previous [lindex $unnumbered 0]
set subcounter 1

for {set i 1} {$i <= [llength $unnumbered]} {incr i} {
  if {$previous == [lindex $unnumbered $i]} {
    lappend numbered $previous.$subcounter
    incr subcounter
  } else {
    if {$subcounter > 1} {
      lappend numbered $previous.$subcounter
    } else {
      lappend numbered $previous
    }
    set subcounter 1
  }
  set previous [lindex $unnumbered $i]
}
```